# DIY Ring Light: Grounding Bulbs in Circuit

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

I'm looking at making a DIY ring light using multiple fluorescent light bulbs. I'm in New Zealand and we get [230-240V](http://www.newzealand.com/int/feature/new-zealand-electricity-and-communication/) and an current of [10A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AS/NZS_3112). I know from this I could rig up to 24 100W bulbs in series onto the ring. Although it is likely I won't have more than 10-15.

Here is an example ring light.

[image: Example ring light]

My question is this, how should I go about grounding this circuit? I've done some physics and am happy with power and voltage equations but was always a bit fuzzy on the concept of grounding and how it should properly be carried out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would [Electrical Engineering SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) be a better home for your question?

Comment: It most likely would! I didn't know about them, so thank you :) I'll head on over there.

Answer (score 1):

First, do not put them "in series"! Each is powered from the mains ie they are in parallel.

Second, earthing is typically applied to any external metalwork that anyone might come into contact where there is any danger of the live coming loose and touching that metal. Think worst case fault conditions.

Finally, the fact you have to ask these question means you probably should not be doing this, at least without advice from a real electrician. Try and find one locally who might spare a few minutes to look over your plans and circuit diagram. Assuming you have one...